# Can we do a HTML design using table like this?

Tags: html

Can we do a HTML design using  like this ?[image]

Tried using colspan and rowspan, but not able to add the rowspan in middle.

Comment: It's recommended not to use the table for HTML layout. Anyway, You can make it using nested table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rowspan="2"` in middle `td` of first row

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" bordercolor="#FF0004"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">left top</td>
    <td rowspan="2" align="center">center</td>
    <td align="right">right top</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">left bottom</td>
    <td align="right">right bottom</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```